# Recover cron jobs accidently removed with crontab -r

Tags: linux, cron

I entered `crontab -r` instead of `crontab -e` and all my `cron` jobs have been removed.

What is the best way (or is there one) to recover those jobs?

Comment: Is it just me or wouldn't it make more sense for crontab -r to ask yes/no by default??

Comment: I think having a yes/no prompt would be a great idea. especially since e & r are right next to each other.. and `crontab -e` is a really common cron command.

Comment: To futureproof, instead of `crontab -e` consider using a variation of this process (assuming `$HOME` directory): `crontab -l >.crontab ; vi .crontab ; sleep 2 && crontab .crontab` and thereafter `vi .crontab ; sleep 2 && crontab .crontab`. I have an extension to `vi` that returns status indicating whether or not the file contents changed during the edit. I can then `ifvi .crontab && crontab .crontab`. (But that extension is out of scope for a comment.)

Comment: In 7 or so years of admin work I have never had this happen to me. Now I am scared. Time to start backing up the crontabs regularly.

Comment: If you have vim set to keep an undo file, you may be able to dig through those manually to rescue some text. Running `ls *crontab*` in your `undodir` should pull up a list of files you can parse (lots of gibberish, but lines I cared about were in plaintext).

Comment: This has happened to me twice already. It's the worst idea ever to have `e` for edit and `r` for remove with absolutely no prompt whatsoever!!

Comment: First thing to do, `alias crontab=crontab -i`. But crontab should have made that default, given that e & r are next to each other...

Comment: This could be a nearest hack... `0 0 * * * /usr/bin/crontab -l > ~/.crontab.bak`

Comment: I didn't even give -r. I just entered "crontab" and it nuked everything. That's insane.

Comment: Mac OS does't support the -i flag on crontab, unfortunately.

Comment: Manage your `crontabs` locally or always follow `crontab -e` with `crontab -l >$HOME/etc/crontabs/crontab.$(tshhmmss)`. `tshhmmss` is a `date` alias producing `2016-Nov-29-124124` unique to-the-second timestamps.

Comment: ok someone didn't look at the fucking keyboard when he was designing crontab

Comment: Might be worth considering having a git repository containing the crontabs. Crontabs are stored /var/spool/cron. Not sure if it is a good idea to create the git repo here. Otherwise, just use a soft link to the location in an external git repo. Add a crontab (irony) to commit changes. Create a separate user (cronbak) or pick one that will never modify it's crontab. Might need to give the users elevated privileges as sudoer.

Comment: I would add `alias crontab='crontab -i'` to `nano ~/.bashrc`. At least this is the login script for Debian.

Comment: Something tells me crontab guys are in DVORAK team

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`crontab -r` removes the only file containing the cron jobs.

So if you did not make a backup, your only recovery options are:

- On RedHat/CentOS, if your jobs have been triggered before, you can find the cron log in `/var/log/cron`. The file will help you rewrite the jobs again.
- Another option is to recover the file using a file recovery tool. This is less likely to be successful though, since the system partition is usually a busy one and corresponding sectors probably have already been overwritten.
- On Ubuntu/Debian, if your task has run before, try `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: I could not voted you up but this answer was some how useful for me. thankx

Comment: @RajaRassani You can mark the answer is a correct one with a tick mark, though. Thanks for feed back!

Comment: this just happened to me :) total bummer.. I do use virtual servers and backup them up regularly..so I'm going to spin up a backup.. and get the deleted crontabs

Comment: +1 for being straightforward :}

Comment: You can try your luck looking for a backup made by the editor in /tmp/crontab.wpMhKS (of course the name may change). It may not be the most recent version but in my case it helped a lot

Comment: @JongBor dude, you saved my day.

Answer (score 28):

If you have no `/var/log/cron` file you can recover the commands (but not the timings) from the `syslog`.

```
grep 'CRON.*(yourusername)' /var/log/syslog
```

you can then figure out most timings by looking at the datestamps.

Comment: On ubuntu the file is `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @ Aurelijus Rozenas I accidentally added sys to  the directory path it should be /var/log/syslog, I corrected my post.

Comment: `grep 'CRON.*(yourusername)' /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @Aidin you are my savior!  Note to self: Never edit the crontab file while server space is full.

Comment: Phew that was close! I've now added a cron to backup my crontab everyday :)

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` stores last day logs or less. In my case I needed  `sudo zgrep 'CRON.*(yourusername)' /var/log/syslog*`

Answer (score 6):

It sucks, but if you run `crontab -r` your crontab is gone forever. And unless you have a backup of it somewhere, you must grep through syslog files to get an idea of what/when jobs were being run, and recreate.

A good trick to avoid such problem is to add the following line to your crontab:

```
@daily          crontab -l > $HOME/.crontab
```

This way your crontab is backed up every day to `$HOME/.crontab`, so if you delete it by accident, a relatively recent copy is available and can be installed by:

```bsh
crontab < $HOME/.crontab
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional preventative measure in addition to backing up data, as mentioned by @anishsane, the `-i` flag will "prompt before deleting user's crontab". So, if you run `crontab -i -r`, it will give a nice

```
crontab: really delete <user>'s crontab? (y/n)
```

At which point you can select y or n. Of course, you don't want to type that out every time, so put this in your bash config and forget about it:

```
alias crontab="crontab -i"
```

As the `-i` flag doesn't affect any other command

Comment: Good suggestion but this doesn't really work if you wanted execute -e but instead mistyped to -r 

Answer (score -7):

`vi /var/spool/cron/*user*` or if you're the `root` user then `vi /var/spool/cron/root`

Comment: This is worse. It edits the spool files without notifying `cron` that the file has been edited. It also won't work when the user has accidentally deleted their `crontab` because there is no file to edit.

Comment: Upvote from me for actually stating the location of the crontab. I had an entire system backup and could easily retrieve my cronjobs. Thanks!